# Comment appelle-t-on les mots qui finissent par "erie", du genre: "coquetterie", "poterie", "agacerie", "buverie", "niaiserie", etc.?

Tags: grammaire, linguistique, suffixes, morphologie

J'ai le français comme langue première, et j'essaie de trouver si une impression que j'ai à propos de la langue est un phénomène réel. Les mots comme ceux indiqués dans le titre, et ceux comme "plomberie", "rapinerie", "tromperie", "galanterie", "faquinerie", etc., sont, premièrement, qu'un sous-ensemble de la totalité des mots qui finissent par "erie", mais deuxièmement semblent avoir en commun le caractère d'être:

- Premièrement, des mots secondaires qui se fondent sur un substantif, verbe ou adjectif antérieur (coquet, pot, agacer, boire, niaiser, plomb, rapine, tromper, galant, faquin, etc.)
- Deuxièmement, à partir du mot primaire, ils y ajoutent le sens de "être du genre de", ou "être des exemples de". Par example, de la coquetterie, c'est de faire des choses coquettes; de la poterie, des choses comme des pots; une agacerie, c'est un exemple de ce qu'on fait quand on agace quelqu'un; une galanterie, c'est ce que fait un galant; de même pour faquinerie et faquin, etc. etc.

Je me demandais, par hasard, si ce genre de mot est une exemplification d'un concept en grammaire, ou en morphologie linguistique; il me semble qu'on peut trouver plusieurs mots secondaires de ce genre, qui sont une sorte de procédé appliqué à un mot primaire, pour le faire finir en "erie" et lui donner le sens souligné dans le deuxième point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'abord ce processus est  morphologique, c'est **la nominalisation**.  La catégorie grammaticale est changée par l'affixe, dans ce cas le suffixe -erie.

> La [nominalisation](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-113477.php) est le fait de former un nom à partir d'un
> verbe ou d'un adjectif. Elle n'a pas de règle spécifique.

Il y a plusieurs suffixes qui arrivent à changer un verbe ou un adjectif en substantif, comme -*tion, -ure, -tude,* ou *-erie.*

Pour le suffixe ***-erie*** en particulier, le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?14;s=668509275;r=1;nat=;sol=3;) donne les dérivations suivants et les significations de valeur qu'ils ont en commun ; je souligne quelques exemples que tu as déjà trouvés :

> ERIE, suff. [Suff. formateur de subst. féminins.] I. Le dér. a une
> valeur dépréciative, affective ou fréquentative. A. [La base est un
> subst. désignant une pers., ou un adj. substantivable s'appliquant à
> une pers. (parfois aussi un adj. non substantivable).]
>
> 1. Le dér. exprime un trait de caractère ou un comportement : ânerie, avocasserie, badauderie, bégueulerie, bigoterie, bouffonnerie,
>    bougrerie, braverie, cagoterie, canaillerie, charlatanerie,
>    charognerie, connerie, **coquetterie**, coquinerie, courtisanerie,
>    crapulerie, cuistrerie, dégueulasserie, diablerie, douilletterie,
>    drôlerie, effronterie, espièglerie, étourderie, filouterie, fourberie,
>    friponnerie, fripouillerie, fumisterie, **galanterie**, gaminerie,
>    gauloiserie, gloutonnerie, goinfrerie, goujaterie, gredinerie,
>    gueuserie, ivrognerie, jobarderie, ladrerie, loufoquerie, maniaquerie,
>    mesquinerie, momerie, muflerie, **niaiserie**, nigauderie, ourserie,
>    pédanterie, pingrerie, pitrerie, pleutrerie, polissonnerie,
>    poltronnerie, pruderie, rosserie, rouerie, saloperie, sauvagerie,
>    sensiblerie, sournoiserie, tartufferie, truanderie, vacherie.  Spéc.
>    Le dér. désigne des relations familières : camaraderie, copinerie.
>
> B. [La base est un verbe.]
>
> 1. Le dér. a une valeur dépréc. et exprime notamment :  la **tromperie** et la vantardise : cachotterie, duperie, flagornerie, flatterie,
>    hâblerie, menterie (vieilli), piperie (vieilli), tricherie, tromperie,
>    vanterie (vieilli)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la réponse!

Comment: Bon et bien bienvenue sur French Language SE. Attendons un peu comme d'autres réponses sont possibles.  Sinon j'espère que tu continues à poser des questions.